# Remove delimiter from n th to n+mth occurrence in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

There is a condition that every line is only having four "," delimiters, if a line is more than 4 delimiters, i would like to remove the delimiter from the third "," to nth delimiter so that each lines remain 4 delimiters only.

Original array (`$text`):

```
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,c,d,e
a,b,c,c,c,d,e
e,f,g,h,i
e,f,g,g,h,e,i
a,b,c,c,b,c,c,d,e
```

Desired output arrays:

`$newtext`:

```
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,cc,d,e
a,b,ccc,d,e
e,f,g,h,i
e,f,ggh,e,i
a,b,ccbcc,d,e
```

Take "a,b,c,c,c,d,e" as example
The way i am thinking is to

1. Find the occurrence of "," in $text
2. If the count is more than 4

   - check the index of the ","
   - Remove from the 3th & 4th ","   loop from 3 to a variable(4) is calculated by (3) + total occurrence of "," (6) - Each line allowed delimiters (4)  - (1)
      3+6-4-1 = 4

I tried my best to parse the script as below but not getting the correct result...

Code:

```bsh
$text = get-content -path "D:\Temp\test\text.txt"

For ($i = 0; $i -le $text.count - 1; $i++) {
    if ($text[$i].split(',').count -gt 4) {

        $separatorArray = ($text[$i] | Select-String "," -AllMatches).Matches.Index

        For ($linei = 3; $linei -le 3 + $text[$i].split(',').count - 4; $linei++) {
            $newtext = $text[$i].remove($separatorArray[$linei], 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you need the - really rather odd - _central grouping_ of extra items? it would be quite easy to convert `a,b,c,c,b,c,c,d,e` to `a,b,c,c,bccde` since PoSh has a way to add leftovers to the last slot in an array ... >>> `'a,b,c,c,b,c,c,d,e' -split ',', 5 -replace ',' -join ','` <<<

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way of approaching the problem:

1. Split on *all* occurences of end
2. Skip if more than 5 resulting substrings (ie. 4 delimiters)
3. Chunk the 5+ resulting substrings into:

   - "Start" - first two items before the third delimiter
   - "End" - last two items
   - "Middle" - anything in between
4. Concatenate anything that falls into the "middle" bucket
5. Join together Start, concatenated Middle and End parts together with the separator:

```bsh
$testInput = @'
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,c,d,e
a,b,c,c,c,d,e
e,f,g,h,i
e,f,g,g,h,e,i
a,b,c,c,b,c,c,d,e
a,b,c
'@ -split '\r?\n'

$delimiter = ','

foreach($s in $testInput){
    # Split by delimiter
    $parts = $s.Split($delimiter)

    if($parts.Count -le 5){
        # 4 delimiters or less, return string as-is, and then skip ahead
        $s
        continue
    }

    # Chunk into start, middle and end parts
    $start = $parts |Select-Object -First 2
    $middle = $parts |Select-Object -Skip 2 |Select-Object -SkipLast 2
    $end = $parts |Select-Object -Last 2

    # Concatenate $middle with no separator, join start + middle + end by original delimiter
    @(
        $start
        $middle -join ''
        $end
    ) -join $delimiter
}
```

This is not necessarily the most performant or memory-friendly solution, so if you need this for high volume data processing you might want to take a low-level string manipulation approach (check out the `Substring`, `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf` string methods in particular)